# Trying to copy Outlook's .pst file while it's open results in file lock error

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, lock

I'm trying to use a simple folder copy as a nightly backup for the `Outlook 2007` .pst file that contains all the mail, etc. But the copy operation results in this error on `%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\Outlook.pst` file:

[image]

I understand that this happens because Outlook is open. So I'm curious if there's a setting or some other way to prevent it from locking its `.pst` file?

(I remember `Outlook Express` did not use to lock its data file, as I was doing the same to back it up.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent Outlook to lock OST/PST files connected to the active profile. But you still can copy these files if you really need it using [Volume Shadow Copy service and robocopy](http://ithelp.cveg.uark.edu/IT_Help/Documents_files/backup.pdf).